# Git log between 2 commits for a given directory

Tags: git, git-log

Is there a way to get git log between 2 commits for a particular directory

```
git log --oneline commitid_dfgdsdfga..HEAD --follow common/*
```

The above did not work

Comment: Why doesn't this work? What do you see? and what do you expect to see?

Comment: I am expecting to see all the changes in directory "common"

Comment: Changes? Won't this log commits?

Comment: As [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) rather clearly states, `--follow` can only follow *one* file. Git does not store directories; it stores only files, whose names have slashes embedded in them. If there's one file name that matches the `common/*` pattern, that's the one file `git log --follow` will follow. If there are two or more such file names, or no such file names, you're out of luck here.

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes you are right commits, looking for all the commits since a givencommitid to head

Comment: I don't understand the phrase "for a particular directory". What is it that you are trying to find out, exactly?

Comment: we have a monorepo and each directory in that repo corresponds to a artifact/package. While building we want to know if there are any changes in each directory after the previous build